# Mac OSX sandbox and public keys

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

Is it somehow possible to access a user's public key files (located in `~/.ssh`) in a sandboxed Mac OSX application?

Comment: Are you running as that user or another?

Comment: I'm guessing no (since your app lives within it's own sandbox), but what are you trying to do?

Comment: See the comment on Jonathan's post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple consider SSH keys to be confidential user information. You must ask for permission to access them using NSOpenPanel.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. `~/.ssh` is outside your sandbox, so you can't access it unless the user gives you permission (for example, by selecting a file inside it in an `NSOpenPanel`.)

Note that most keys and certificates are stored in the Keychain on Mac OS X rather than in a dot directory. The Keychain APIs are accessible even within a sandbox. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may be able to accomplish it through the keychain.

Comment: I wish to connect to SSH servers with libssh2. For public key authentication and ssh agents I need to read the keys from the filesystem.

Comment: If you're sandboxed, you can't open that file. So, you're out of luck.